# Get a list of Make prerequisites

Tags: makefile, static-analysis

I would like to get a list of prerequisites that `make` would use to create/update its targets. This would be used to gather a list of source files to feed into a static analysis tool. I could do something like Clang's [scan-build](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/scan-build.html) does and override the compiler variable with a shell script that appends to a file or something, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your choices are:

1. do like scan-build does
2. parse the output from `make -qp` (possibly `-np` I'm not sure).
3. parse make yourself

in descending order of simplicity/ease (assuming you want to build at the same time).

If you don't want to require actually building then I believe item one cycles to the bottom of the order.

[`remake`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) may also be of use here though I don't recall offhand.